# Why is the CPU on my HP suddenly under clocked and seemingly cannot go higher?

Tags: cpu, hp-pavilion, voltage, clockspeed, ghz

My laptop base speed is 2.19 sometimes my FPS drop to 1.89 GHz but it be stuck on 2.19 GHz and and it use to overheat a lot which made my PC slower so I had to use a cooling pad and now it's stuck on 2.19 GHz.

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried going to my power plan putting the minimum and maximum processor to  100% and it just made me stuck at my base speed. What I can do at this point besides trying MSI Afterburner? I want to make sure I can fix this without using MSI Afterburner.

Comment: Why not just use standard power settings and let the CPU manage itself. It should be able to do this without overheating or running much at full speed.

Comment: MSI Afterburner only applies to your GPU.  Does [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1219054/processor-speed-locked-at-low-ghz-after-computer-runs-for-a-few-minutes?rq=1) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

First, go to your HP Power Management settings and reset to default.

Restart the computer.

Now update the BIOS, Power and other drivers using the HP System Updater App.

Check that power management is default and Intel Speed Step should take over and run the computer at the best speed.

Here is a good beginning article for Intel CPU management by itself (humans cannot do better).

[CPU Power Management](https://metebalci.com/blog/a-minimum-complete-tutorial-of-cpu-power-management-c-states-and-p-states/)

> **Introduction** How does CPU save power ? You will learn all the basics about the CPU power management in this post.
>
> The processor/CPU is designed to operate forever under a specific
> load. As almost none of us are doing a 24x7 calculation employing all
> the resources of the CPU continuously, it is most of the time not
> operating in its designed maximum. So what is the point of keeping the
> whole CPU powered on at its full capacity ? This is the point of CPU
> power management. The power management topic covers much more than
> this, including the RAM, GPU etc., but I am going to tell you only
> about the CPU side of the story in this post.
>
> If you know about C-states and P-states and how CPU enters to and
> exits from these states, probably there is nothing new in this post
> for you. If not, continue reading.
>
> I was planning to include a few real-world examples from Linux, but
> the post was getting longer and taking even more time to finish, so I
> will do that in another post.
>
> The general information in this post is applicable to all modern CPUs
> but the details can be very specific to the individual CPU (esp. to
> the processor family) and I am using an Intel® Xeon® E3-1245 v5 @
> 3.50GHz, this is a Xeon E3–1200 v5 series (formerly Skylake) processor (model number 0x5e).

If all the above has been done and there are still issues, look for a hardware cause:  thermal compound, fan not working, dust build up all of which can prevent a machine from running faster as it could overheat.

Comment: I don't think i have intel speedstep.

Comment: Speed Step or a feature like it it has been around for decades. It is most unlikely your CPU cannot manage its own speed. Follow what I outlined above.

Comment: Alright i got my hp coolsense and it still the same.

Comment: If you have done all I suggested, start looking at hardware causes:  thermal compound, fan not working correctly, dust build up.